# Flask RadioField is not working in form POST

Tags: python-3.x, flask-wtforms

Can someone please help resolving RadioField Post issue in below code snippet
As below code is not moving `form.validate_on_submit()`

```
**forms.py**
class validatingSPLForm(FlaskForm): 
    srcfile = FileField('Select Source ZIP', validators=[FileRequired(), FileAllowed(['zip'], 'Only ZIP files are allowed')])
    submit = SubmitField("Validate")
    proceed = IntegerField()
    SPLFiles = RadioField('SPL', choices=[])
    archiveresult = []
```

```
**routes.py**
app.route('/validatingSPLForm', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def validatingSPLForm():
    form = validatingSPLForm()    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():          
           form.SPLFiles.choices = [(elem.name, elem.des) for elem in form.archiveresult]
```

```
**validatingSPLForm.html**
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
{% block content1 %} 
        <div class="content-section">             
            <h6><b class="text-success">"{{ form.srcfile.data.filename }}"</b> is valid, select one of the below SPL for further validation </h6>
            {{ form.SPLFiles() }}            
        </div>

{% endblock content1 %}
```

Comment: got any error ? if so please update the same ..

Comment: Is this code complete? I don't see a submit button...?